# '-in' is an invalid command.

Tags: public-key, openssl

While trying to convert private key into public key i get this error message.

I used 
"openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.key 4096"
to generate the private key and 
used
"openssl -in private.key -pubout -out public.key" 
to generate the public key.

what went wrong,why do I get this error

Answer (score 3):

This happened because openssl tool syntax requires a command name as the first parameter. 
In your case it should be

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out publickey.out
```

Notice the **rsa** command name.